# Cannot instantiate a random object from a collection

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I am making a Xmas tree with a geometry node
I want to create an Ornament, but I could not instantiate it Randomly using Collection Info
When I changed the Instance index, everything just changed to the same different object
And it's hard to use because it's already normal direction and rotated, so I want to improve it.
This is the object I created
[image]

This Xmas tree node
[image]

The results I want
[image]

Comment: I recommend sharing the blend file using https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to realize the curves (with a *Realize Instances* node) before you do the second instances on points, and use a random value.